# Open new window in asp:linkButton Click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How we open new window on a asp:linkButton Click event programmatically. In my program there is a textbox (named : txtUrl) and linkButton (or Button). On the link button click I need to get url form my text box (txtUrl) and open that url in new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to open Window by getting URL from Textbox. Write below code in aspx file:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Function Linkclick()
    {
       myWindow=window.open(document.getElementByID("textboxid").value),'','width=200,height=100')
       myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>")
       myWindow.focus()
    }
    </script>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="Linkclick();">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Once again Thank you ... But a small change to code like

        var str = $("#<%=txt_firstUrl.ClientID %>").val();
        myWindow = window.open(str, '', 'width=200,height=100');

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenWindow()
    {
       window.open('Details.aspx','_blank','height=450,width=500,scrollbars=0,location=1,toolbar=0');
    }
    </script>
```

Then on your aspx page on button/linkbutton etc. just use a OnClientClick event

```
 OnClientClick="OpenWindow();return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call function onclick event of link button.
In function you can write following code

```
function OpenWindow()
{
    Window.open(document.getElementByID("textboxid").value);    
}
```